# MySQL using subqueries instead of JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show the names of all artists which have at least one female member each.

The Members table looks as follows:

```
Members
-------
MemberID, Firstname, Lastname, Address, Gender
```

The Artists table looks as follows:

```
Artists
-------
ArtistID, Artistname, City
```

The tables are related using the xRefArtistsMembers table, which is as follows:

```
xRefArtistsMembers
------------------
MemberID, ArtistID
```

I have formulated the following subquery:

```
select
  ar.artistname from artists ar
where
  ar.artistid in
  (
    (
      select
        x.artistid
      from
        xrefartistsmembers x
    )
    in
    (
      select
        m.memberid
      from
        members m
    )
  );
```

which does not compile. Again, my question is: I need to show the names of all artists which have at least one female member each. With using only subqueries.

Comment: You don't have a column that indicates the gender of member.

Comment: one female member each ? how will you find .. Im not seeing any Gender column

Comment: Let me apologize, I accidently forgot to include that crucial peice of record data.

Comment: Is this homework?  Why can't you use a join?

Comment: What does your title mean? Do you **have** to use sub-queries instead of JOIN?

Comment: Yes. I prefer to use subqueries instead of JOIN, specifically because it runs faster AND as a learning experience.

Comment: I do not know how to use subqueries. I have read books and online sources but I am still confused on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT *
  FROM artists a
 WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM xRefArtistsMembers x
   WHERE artistid = a.artistid
     AND EXISTS
  (
    SELECT * 
      FROM members 
     WHERE memberid = x.memberid
       AND gender = 'female'
  )
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a06d/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks for your response. For some reason the following query: select * from artists ar
where artistname in (select gender from members where members.gender = 'F'); For some reason produces an EMPTY SET>

Comment: You're quite welcome. ;) How can the query you mentioned in the comment above produce anything when you compare `artistname` in outer  select to `gender` in inner subquery..?

Comment: Very correct. Ok Thanks I think I understand more simply by the 'EXISTS' statement